# Preventing a custom piece of text from appearing ON ALL Highcharts present on a page ← piece of text inserted using {events:{load:function(){var

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

So, I added a **piece of text** on to an [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)-chart, using `{events:{load:function(){var`...`}}}`

The complete part of this code (to add such a **piece of text**) is (in a MWE):

```
{
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var e = this.renderer.label("test").css({
                width: "200px",
                color: "black",
                fontSize: "12px"
            }).add();
            e.align(Highcharts.extend(["label"]["getBBox()"]), null, "spacingBox")
        }
    }
},
```

This code is, in a Highchart-code, put inside `$(function(){Highcharts.theme={`...`,chart:` More information can be found in the [Highcharts API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts).

---

Now the problem is, that this code is making the **piece of tex**t is rendered *on all the Highcharts present on the page*; whereas I actually just would like it to be rendered *on to 1 single chart* (the one where the code is inserted in).

Many thanks for any ideas on how to circumvent this.

Comment: Just don't set this in the theme. When you create that one, chosen chart, then set that option. Something like this: `$("#container").highcharts({ chart: { events: { load: your_callback } } });`

Comment: @PawełFus Worked like a charm. Well spotted. Thanks for your clear analytic thinking. You can make this into a perfect answer, if you'd wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't set this in the theme. When you create that one, chosen chart, then set that option. Something like this:

```
$("#container").highcharts({ chart: { events: { load: your_callback } } });
```